# C# finding the max value of ints, then outputting the variable name of the maximum

Tags: c#

I'm looping through a 2d array, and at the end of each row I need to find the maximum value. There are 6 values in each row so using Math.Max repeating can be long. So is there anything other than Math.Max to use? After that, I don't need to know the value that is ended, instead, I need to know the variable name of the highest value. Any suggestions?

Here's my current code.

```
        for(int col = 0; col < geneArrays.GetLength(0); col++)
                    {
                        for(int row = 0; row < geneArrays.GetLength(1); row++)
                        {
                            float G = 0f, Y = 0f, H = 0f, X = 0f, W = 0f;
                            if (geneArrays[col][row] == 'G')
                            {
                                G += 0.6f;
                            }
                            else if (geneArrays[col][row] == 'Y')
                            {
                                Y = +0.6f;
                            }
                            else if (geneArrays[col][row] == 'H')
                            {
                                H = +0.6f;
                            }
                            else if (geneArrays[col][row] == 'X')
                            {
                                X = +0.6f;
                            }
                            else if (geneArrays[col][row] == 'W')
                            {
                                W = +0.6f;
                            }
                            string nameOfVariable = nameof(Math.Max(G,Y);
                        }
                    }
```

I'm clearly using nameof incorrectly, I think the Math.Max is making it error.

Comment: In this case, using LINQ with OrderBy and Take(1) might work, when adding to a collection appropriately. The else-ifs can also be entirely eliminated when making the “name” part of the data. See also: Dictionary’ies (which is a kind of collection).

Comment: I did read the documentation, and it detailed that "A nameof expression produces the name of a variable," Which seems exactly what I want. I'm not sure that it's too far off either. When testing random logic statements, displaying out the "nameof(aVariable)" works just fine.

Comment: What is the “variable name” of X + Y? That’s about the same as a “variable name” of an arbitrary method call expression. Compare to: “var x = 1; var s = nameof(x);”

Comment: Either way, I'm not sure how to use LINQ, so I don't really understand. From what the documentation says, it sounds like it could work for modifying the data in the way that I need, I'm just not sure how to go through the array for it.

Comment: Would you be willing to show off what type 
"geneArrays" is? 

char[,]?
string[,]?

Do you perhaps have a test input sample we could use, to reproduce a result?

Comment: Yes I know their bad variable names. :) but for the purpose of the program, they are exactly how they need to be. They are not arbitrary, they are the names of the data that I am using.

Comment: I am not talking about the name itself, that is irrelevant. 
But their type is not:
do you have a multi-dimonsal array of char? strings?
The code doesn't build, so I need to know that you know precisely what data you are  pushing through your method, is valid.

Comment: Great time to learn LINQ. Anyway, the initial loop can go something like this: Create a dictionary of string -> float; For each iteration, let key = array[col][row]; If not key in dictionary, add dict[key] = 0.6; otherwise dict[key] = dict[key] + 0.6 .. now there is a collection of pairs (key, value) tuples, with distinct keys, which can be ordered by value. Once the highest tuple is found by value, return the key (aka “name”).

Comment: geneArrays is char[][] that is made up of multiple genePlacement[]'s

Comment: @Issayah, excellent. 
Can you provide an input sample? So I don't have to fabricate some pseudo example? 
Like, say from a unit test you already have running?

Comment: There is no premade list of data that I use. Each char array is made up of a string that can only be made up of 5 different letters - GYHXW. They are random in which they come in. The set comes in 5. The string of letters is made into an array of chars. I then take all arrays and filter their indexes into their own arrays, so all index 0s go into their own array. They are then compared to see which letter occurs the most. I only need to get the name of the letter that occurs the most, and disregard how many times it appears. Does that help? Again, I only need the name of the variable.

Comment: I provided a sort of pseudo answer. without some proper input examples, I made up my own. 

You should really build a unit test for yourself for a method like this.

Comment: also you are finding the max value of floats, not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.Max returns the value of the two input values. You will only know the value of G,Y in this example.
But that makes no sense, considering you have multiple values that then are completely ignored. 
I would recommend you add them to a list, and sort them so you can find the top variable:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[,] dataArray = new char[3, 10];

            //Test data input generation.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dataArray[0, 0] = 'G';
                dataArray[0, 1] = 'Y';
                dataArray[0, 2] = 'H';
                dataArray[0, 3] = 'X';
                dataArray[0, 4] = 'W';
                dataArray[0, 5] = 'G';
                dataArray[0, 6] = 'G';
                dataArray[0, 7] = 'Y';
                dataArray[0, 8] = 'W';
                dataArray[0, 9] = 'X';
                dataArray[1, 0] = 'G';
                dataArray[1, 1] = 'Y';
                dataArray[1, 2] = 'H';
                dataArray[1, 3] = 'X';
                dataArray[1, 4] = 'W';
                dataArray[1, 5] = 'G';
                dataArray[1, 6] = 'G';
                dataArray[1, 7] = 'Y';
                dataArray[1, 8] = 'W';
                dataArray[1, 9] = 'X';
                dataArray[2, 0] = 'G';
                dataArray[2, 1] = 'Y';
                dataArray[2, 2] = 'H';
                dataArray[2, 3] = 'X';
                dataArray[2, 4] = 'W';
                dataArray[2, 5] = 'G';
                dataArray[2, 6] = 'G';
                dataArray[2, 7] = 'Y';
                dataArray[2, 8] = 'W';
                dataArray[2, 9] = 'X';
            }



            List<List<NameAndValue>> totalList = new List<List<NameAndValue>>();


            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                List<NameAndValue> geneNameValues = CreateNameAndValueList();
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    switch (dataArray[j, k])
                    {
                        case 'G':
                            {
                                geneNameValues.First(x => x.Name.Equals('G')).Value += 0.6m;
                                break;
                            }
                        case 'Y':
                            {
                                geneNameValues.First(x => x.Name.Equals('Y')).Value += 0.6m;
                                break;
                            }
                        case 'H':
                            {
                                geneNameValues.First(x => x.Name.Equals('H')).Value += 0.6m;
                                break;
                            }
                        case 'X':
                            {
                                geneNameValues.First(x => x.Name.Equals('X')).Value += 0.6m;
                                break;
                            }
                        case 'W':
                            {
                                geneNameValues.First(x => x.Name.Equals('W')).Value += 0.6m;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                totalList.Add(geneNameValues);
            }
            int listCount = 0;
            foreach (List<NameAndValue> list in totalList)
            {
                list.Sort((x, y) => x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));
                NameAndValue highestValue = list.Last();
                Console.WriteLine("List-count: " + listCount + " The highest value was: " + highestValue.Name + " with a score of: " + highestValue.Value);
                listCount++;
            }
        }

        public static List<NameAndValue> CreateNameAndValueList()
        {
            NameAndValue item1 = new NameAndValue() { Name = 'G', Value = 0m };
            NameAndValue item2 = new NameAndValue() { Name = 'Y', Value = 0m };
            NameAndValue item3 = new NameAndValue() { Name = 'H', Value = 0m };
            NameAndValue item4 = new NameAndValue() { Name = 'X', Value = 0m };
            NameAndValue item5 = new NameAndValue() { Name = 'W', Value = 0m };

            List<NameAndValue> valueList = new List<NameAndValue>() { item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 };
            return valueList;
        }
    }

    public class NameAndValue
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public char Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I suggest you setup a unit test for something like this:

Provide a controlled set of input data, where you are sure what the expected result should be.

Then consider your expected value borders. 
Build up a enough samples that you are sure, test will catch any logic errors in it, and then proceed to start optimizing your logic. There is loads to do.

This is something of a re-write I am aware. But it does perform your requested function. Now you just need to change the hardcoded 3,10 values into your foreach system.

but without better input, I can't be arsed to write a realistic implementation.

Also I changed float to decimal C# is just bad at rounding floats. especially in calculations. If you want to see numbers that make sense to the human brain, use Decimal.

Just copy this code into a "namespace" set of {}, and it will execute. And long as the namespace is a console application :)